# 'pluck' refetch cached associations every time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I know that `pluck` is more performant than using `select` or `mapping object` because of the cost of object construction.
But i found that `pluck` does not use the cache of `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`. For example:

```
irb(main):001:0> u = User.take
irb(main):002:0> puts Benchmark.measure { u.rides.map(&:id) }
  Ride Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "rides".* FROM "rides" WHERE "rides"."user_id" = $1  ORDER BY "rides"."created_at" DESC  [["user_id", 1]]
  0.040000   0.020000   0.060000 (  0.072337)
irb(main):003:0> puts Benchmark.measure { u.rides.map(&:id) }  # once again, fetching data from the cache
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000103)
irb(main):004:0> puts Benchmark.measure { u.rides.pluck(&:id) }
  (1.6ms)  SELECT "rides"."id" FROM "rides" WHERE "rides"."user_id" = $1  ORDER BY "rides"."created_at" DESC  [["user_id", 1]]
  0.010000   0.010000   0.020000 (  0.020381)
irb(main):005:0> puts Benchmark.measure { u.rides.pluck(&:id) }  # once again, refetch data from database
  (1.5ms)  SELECT "rides"."id" FROM "rides" WHERE "rides"."user_id" = $1  ORDER BY "rides"."created_at" DESC  [["user_id", 1]]
  0.010000   0.010000   0.020000 (  0.020810)
```

Is that normal? Is it better to use `mapping` or `select` rather than `pluck` with this way?

BTW, i am using Rails-4.

## UPDATES

I am not sure this is a bug, it seems to be fixed by Rails 5. [rails/rails#25976](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/25976)

Answer (score 0):

`pluck` goes to DB every time. It is useful when you don't won't to load all the matching record in memory but just want value(s) of specific column(s).

It may be possible that the records for which you are going to db to get selected column values are already loaded in memory. So that is what your example shows. The first call to `u.rides` loads all records for that user. Subsequent calls to that collection would just use in memory objects for different operations.

I would suggest to read http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/ once.

Comment: I didn't know that `pluck` is not working with cached association. IMO, i figure it should be,  why `pluck` does not support this feature?